# Difficulties with using Python file "run.py" to test performance of an Android OpenCV application

Tags: android, python, opencv

I have difficulties with running a "run.py" file to test my Android OpenCV app. "run.py" file is unmodified and taken from the OpenCV library package from folder ..\modules\ts\misc.
I'm using tutorials from http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AnalyzePerfTestsLogs and http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Android_Java_API_tests , but I get SyntaxErrors in the python compiler. According to the first tutorial, I change directory to my android application project folder, which is created by Eclipse. Is it a correct folder?
Then I type the command from the second tutorial: "python run.py . -a -t java" and I get an error message: 
  "File "run.py", line 274
    print "adb command:", " ".join(self.adb)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

What am I doing wrong? Can you tell me how to run the "run.py" python file in my case? I haven't used any python scripts before, so please forgive me any mistakes.
I want to use the python files which were included in the OpenCV library because I goal is to test the performance of Android OpenCV apps on several Android devices and those python files are the best solution I know.

Comment: Post the full traceback that you get.

Comment: How can I get a traceback?

Comment: You only posted the last few lines of your error message. Post the *entire* thing.

Comment: That's everything I get from the compiler http://tinypic.com/r/2yvox2w/6

Comment: The error message, which I have posted appears when I type directly from windows cmd. When I open python interpreter and type the same command I get a message: >>> run.py . -a -t java
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    run.py . -a -t java
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What Python version are you using? Run `python --version`.

Comment: Python 3.3.0; x64 version, if it will be helpful

Comment: You're running code that's for Python 2.7. You'll need to install Python 2.7.3 to run that Python script.

Comment: Ok, now the script works, but what is the correct build path, which I have to type in the python interpreter? Here you can see the contents of my android opencv project folder http://tinypic.com/r/jjaark/6